# Python | Flask Url_For MissingSchema: Invalid URL Error

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, sqlalchemy

im having an issues while trying to scrape the html from the current page the user is on.. Essentially the user is building a list of exercises to create a workout routine, the user is picking from a Select field, and each time they click the "add" button, it will populate a list of what they have chosen so far. Then I will grab the Text from that list and match it to what I have in my database
**My issue is coming up in requests.get(url_for('createARoutine'))**.

**requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/createaroutine': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///createaroutine?**

when testing it with the direct url "http://127.0.0.1:5000/createaroutine" my error changes to **werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/createaroutine'. Did you mean 'createARoutine' instead?**

```
@app.route("/createaroutine", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createARoutine():
    """
    present form to creatine new routine, each time user clicks to 
    add an exercise, show the exercise to the side"""
    form = CreateRoutineForm()
    query = Exercises.query.all()
    choices = [(c.id, c.name) for c in query]
    form.exercises.choices = choices

    # collect all exercises and add to routine, 
    # also add routine to users favorites
  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        this_html = requests.get(url_for('createARoutine'))     <----ERROR
        soup = BeautifulSoup(this_html, 'html.parser')
        p = soup.find_all("li", {"id": "exerciseChoices"})
        print(p)
        return redirect(url_for('showWorkoutRoutines'))
    return render_template("createRoutine.html", form=form)
```

`

Comment: You can make a hidden input and set it's value yo window.location.href using javascript and when user click , it sends the value and you can get it using flask. And set the url to the value from received from html.

Comment: There is also request.url which gives you the current full url on the page user is.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, as `requests` needs a fully qualified url, including the server where you are running.

On the other hand, I'm strugling to understand why you are doing what you are doing! You are calling your own site with a get, instead of accessing the data from where you are. This is a terrible idea. You have all the data you need in the exact function. If you need the html, it's in the template. You should never, ever do what you are doing here.